# MvvmCross Monodroid.Dialog layout like iMessage

Tags: xamarin.android, mvvmcross, monodroid.dialog

I'm using MvvmCross and Dialog to create an iPhone and Android app. I've hit a bit of a stumbler when trying to layout a screen similar to the iMessage app on the iPhone.

I basically need a scrollview which takes up most of the screen but has a text entry and submit button stuck to the bottom of the screen. If the list grows to be larger than the height of the screen the list should scroll, preserving the positioning of the text entry and submit button at the bottom of the screen.

In a very quick, dirty and lame attempt I have tried:

```
Root = new RootElement{ 
    new BindableSection<CustomStringElement>(null, () => new CustomStringElement(),(o, i) => {
        //do something when clicked
    }).Bind(bindings, element => element.ItemsSource, vm => vm.Comments),
    new Section{
        new ButtonElement("Test")
    }
};
```

Which obviously pushes the buttonelement down when the list is larger than the screen height.

What I would like to know is how best to achieve this? I know I can create elements using layouts. But what would I lay out for this? I'm thinking this would be much easier to achieve if it were a straight MvxActivity but I don't think I can mix `MvxActivity` and `MvxDialogActivity` - I could be wrong?

How would you achieve this layout?

Answer (score 0):

You can mix dialogs with non-dialogs - so this might be the best way to go.

Also, @csteeg submitted some code last year which enabled dialogs to be used inside linear layouts (scroll views) and listviews (and fragments) - it should be relatively straightforward to use those inside your custom activities - their source code is in https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/tree/v3.1/CrossUI/CrossUI.Droid/Dialog

Comment: And now the obvious - is there a way to do this in Monotouch.Dialog? I have a hacky way of adding a view to the bottom of the main window: AppDelegate._window.AddSubview (comment); but that's not ideal :)

Comment: Sorted it - had to host the Root inside another  controller and did some moving around. Wasn't easy though!

Comment: If you solved your issue answer your own question and accept it.